# Django Custom Authentication Not Authenticating Users

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a Django website, what I want is there to be separate user bases, one is User and another is Agent. Now Agent model does not extend the CustomUser Model. So that Agents can register themselves without being registered as a User first. When I register my Agents through AgentRegister form, my Agent passwords are being hashed properly which I can see in my Admin panel. Now the problem is, even when I enter correct Agent credentials in my AgentSignIn form, I can't log in as an Agent as it says "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive." Same things happens when I enter correct User credentials into UserSignIn form. I can't sign in and it says "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive." Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."  How do I fix this? Neither login is working properly.

My models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='CustomUser_set', blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.')
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name='customuser_set', blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.')


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    
class AgentManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

class Agent(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    agent_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    bio = models.TextField()
    instagram = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='agent_set', blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.')
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name='agent_set', blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.')

    objects = AgentManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'agent_email'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('agent-dashboard', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My forms.py:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('phonenumber',)


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['phonenumber',]


class AgentRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    agent_email = forms.EmailField()
    image = forms.ImageField()
    instagram = forms.URLField(initial="https://")
    facebook = forms.URLField(initial="https://")
    twitter = forms.URLField(initial="https://")
    linkedin = forms.URLField(initial="https://")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Confirm Password')

    class Meta:
        model = Agent
        fields = ['username', 'name', 'agent_email', 'password', 'confirm_password', 'image', 'bio', 'instagram', 'facebook', 'twitter', 'linkedin']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')

        if password and confirm_password and password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        agent = super(AgentRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        agent.agent_email = self.cleaned_data['agent_email']
        agent.image = self.cleaned_data['image']
        agent.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])  # Use set_password to hash the password
        if commit:
            agent.save()
        return agent


class UserSignInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    user_type = forms.CharField(initial='user', widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

class AgentSignInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    user_type = forms.CharField(initial='agent', widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
```

My settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "users.backends.CustomAuthBackend",
]
```

My backends.py:

```
UserModel = get_user_model()

class CustomAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        user_type = kwargs.pop('user_type', None)

        if user_type == 'user':
            try:
                user = UserModel.objects.get(Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username))
            except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
                return None

            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user

        elif user_type == 'agent':
            try:
                agent = Agent.objects.get(Q(username=username) | Q(agent_email=username))
            except Agent.DoesNotExist:
                return None

            if agent.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(agent):
                return agent

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return UserModel.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

My views.py:

```
User = get_user_model()


class UserRegisterView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'users/register.html'
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        login(self.request, self.object)
        return response


class AgentRegisterView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'users/agent_register.html'
    form_class = AgentRegisterForm
    model = Agent

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        login(self.request, self.object, backend="users.backends.AgentBackend")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())


class UserLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'users/login.html'
    form_class = UserSignInForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('home')

class AgentLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'users/agent_login.html'
    form_class = AgentSignInForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('agent-dashboard', kwargs={'slug': self.request.user.slug})


class AgentDashboard(DetailView):
    model = Agent
    template_name = 'users/agent_dashboard.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Agent.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        agent = self.object

        # Line graph: Property clicks
        property_clicks_data = {}
        for property in Property.objects.filter(agent=agent):
            property_clicks_data[property.address] = property.clicks

        plt.plot(property_clicks_data.keys(), property_clicks_data.values())
        plt.xlabel('Property')
        plt.ylabel('Clicks')
        plt.title('Property Clicks')
        plt.xticks()
        clicks_chart_img = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(clicks_chart_img, format='png')
        clicks_chart_img.seek(0)
        clicks_chart_base64 = base64.b64encode(clicks_chart_img.read()).decode('utf-8')
        plt.close()

        # Map: Property locations
        property_data = Property.objects.filter(agent=agent)
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(property_data, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(property_data.values_list('longitude', flat=True), property_data.values_list('latitude', flat=True)))
        world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

        ax = world.plot(figsize=(10, 10), color='lightgrey')
        gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red', markersize=50)
        map_img = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(map_img, format='png')
        map_img.seek(0)
        map_base64 = base64.b64encode(map_img.read()).decode('utf-8')
        plt.close()


        # Pie chart: Clicks distribution
        clicks_distribution_data = [property.clicks for property in Property.objects.filter(agent=agent)]
        plt.pie(clicks_distribution_data, labels=[property.address for property in Property.objects.filter(agent=agent)], autopct='%1.1f%%')
        plt.title('Clicks Distribution')
        pie_chart_img = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(pie_chart_img, format='png')
        pie_chart_img.seek(0)
        pie_chart_base64 = base64.b64encode(pie_chart_img.read()).decode('utf-8')
        plt.close()

        context['clicks_chart'] = clicks_chart_base64
        context['map'] = map_base64
        context['pie_chart'] = pie_chart_base64

        return context


def agent_logout(request):
    username = request.session.get('username')
    if username:
        try:
            agent = Agent.objects.get(username=username)
            agent.is_authenticated = False
            agent.save()
        except Agent.DoesNotExist:
            pass  # Handle the case where the agent does not exist
    logout(request)
    messages.info(request, "")
    return redirect('home')


@login_required
def custom_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.info(request, "")
    return redirect('home')
```

Comment: Not answering to your question. More like want to share this idea: I would stick with the default mechanics. The one that relies on a single User model. To differentiate the type of users I would rely on Groups. All this is built in. So no need to write extra code and maintain it. From my perspective a clean way to go unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: It is true that I do not know what I am doing, I've neve used Django Custom Authentication before, so I want to learn how to have separate user bases. For example, even if I want to build a school website, I would have to have separate user bases like students and teachers and different login urls. So I want to learn how to do it.

Comment: This example with the school: you may keep the actual users in the same table (Django model). Then you'd assign roles (Groups, Permissions). And create appropriate Profiles. One for a student, one for a Teacher. 
There could be separate urls and UI for logins despite the user table is the same. 
Basically a user something needed for auth. Other stuff is domain (business logic) driven.